# Highly correlated variable, when to remove

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset that includes both course number and course name.

For some models such as regression, a Pearson Correlation matrix is obtained and one of any pair of features that are highly correlated are dropped to improve the results.

Since course number/name are categorical features, I am not able to plot the correlation matrix for them, but they have a one-to-one relationship.

Does finding highly correlated pair of features and removing one important for various other models in Machine learning? If I were to use SVM or KNN, or Trees would I have to drop one of the columns (either keep course name or course number)? Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: If you know the relationship is 1-to-1 then you can/should just go ahead and drop one yourself. Some classifier methods will be sensitive to this, others won't, but if it's known a priori that there is a perfect correlation then you lose nothing by going ahead and removing one.

Comment: Most (linear) regression software will automatically detect the collinearity and drop half your variables.  The machine learning methods, if they are any good at all, will do something similar.  In all such cases your model may be difficult to interpret because it could be based on a weird mixture of course names and numbers, depending on arbitrary aspects of the software implementation.